# A subset of roots whose mutual angles agree with those of a simple system

Tags: lie-algebras, reflection, root-systems, coxeter-groups

I would appreciate help/hints solving the following exercise from Humphreys book "Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups", page 11, exercise 1.

> Let $\Phi$ be a root system of rank $n$ of unit vectors in $V$ and let
>   $\Psi\subset\Phi$  be a subset of size $n$. If the mutual angles in
>   $\Psi$ agree with those between the roots of some simple system, then
>   $\Psi$ is a simple root system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my own answer using a proposition which appears later in the book. This leaves me curious whether there is a solution using only the material appearing prior to the exercise.

Denote by $\Delta=\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}\subset\Phi$ the simple system with the same angles as $\Psi=\{\psi_1,\dots,\psi_n\}$. $\Phi$ is also normalized so $(\psi_i,\psi_j)=(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)$ for every $1\leq i,j \leq n$. Denote by $W$ the reflection group generated by the reflections $S_\beta$ such that $\beta\in\Phi$.
We need to show that $\Psi$ is a simple root system ($|\Psi|=n$ therefore it is enough to show that $\Psi$ is linearly independent and that every $\beta\in\Phi$ is a linear combination of $\Psi$ in which all the coefficients have the same sign).

First show that $\Psi$ is linearly independent; assume the contrary, so there is some linear combination $ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i\psi_i = 0$ where not all $c_i$ are equal to zero. Therefore

$$ 
0=
(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\psi_i,\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\psi_i) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j(\psi_i,\psi_j) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_i c_j(\alpha_i,\alpha_j) = 
(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\alpha_i,\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\alpha_i).
$$

Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\alpha_i=0$ where not all $c_i$ are equal to zero, in contradiction to $\Delta$ being linearly independent.

To show that every $\beta\in\Phi$ is a linear combination of $\Psi$ in which all the coefficients have the same sign, we will need the following proposition on page $24$ section $1.14$ of the same book where Humphreys shows that **all** the reflections in $W$ are of the form $S_\beta$ such that $\beta\in\Phi$. That is
$$(*) \; S_\beta\in W \Leftrightarrow \beta\in\Phi $$

Let $T$ be the orthogonal transformation defined by $T(\alpha_i)=\psi_i$ (if $\Phi$ does not span $V$ entirely, then complete $\Delta$ to be a base of $V$ and define that $T$ fixed point wise the additional elements).

Let $\beta$ be a root in $\Phi$ and $\beta=\sum c_i\psi_i$. Applying $T^{-1}$ to both side of the equation we get $T^{-1}(\beta)=\sum c_i T^{-1}(\psi_i)=\sum c_i \alpha_i$. This is a linear combination of $\Delta$, thus proving that $T(\Phi)=\Phi$ shows that all $c_i$ have the same sign completing the proof.

Following $(*)$, it is enough to show that the reflection $S_{T(\beta)}\in W$ in order to show that $T(\beta)\in\Phi$. The following completes the proof (recall that simple reflections generate $W$, thus $S_\beta$ is equal to a composition of some $k$ simple reflection $S_{\alpha_1}\cdots S_{\alpha_k}$):
$$ S_{T(\beta)} = TS_\beta T^{-1} = TS_{\alpha_1}\cdots S_{\alpha_k} T^{-1}  = TS_{\alpha_1}T^{-1}\cdot TS_{\alpha_2}T^{-1}\cdots TS_{\alpha_k} T^{-1} = S_{T(\alpha_1)}\cdots S_{T(\alpha_k)} = S_{\psi_1}\cdots S_{\psi_k} \in W.$$

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Why is $T^{-1}(\beta)$ necessarily a root? Not every linear combination of $\Delta$ is a root.

Comment: That's the purpose of the last bit ($T(\Phi) = \Phi$). Btw, if you find a way to prove this without (*) let me know please.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see now. I am trying to prove it using a similar transformation. T should map the fundamental Weyl chamber to another Weyl chamber but I'm having trouble showing that the image actually is a Weyl chamber. Is your map $T$ making sure mutual angles are preserved?

Comment: Sure, $T$ is orthogonal (btw a Weyl chamber was not defined at this point of the book).

Answer (score 3):

While this question has been inactive for quite some time, I think it is worthwhile to add a solution which only uses material which has been introduced prior to the exercise.
For the sake of completeness I also repeat some of the arguments given in the previous answer.

---

> **Lemma:**
>   Let $V$ be a finite dimensional euclidian vector space.
>   If $v_1, \dotsc, v_n \in V$ are linearly independent, then for $w_1, \dotsc, w_n \in W$ with $(v_i, v_j) = (w_i, w_j)$ for all $i, j$, there exists an orthogonal transformation $T \colon V \to V$ with $Tv_i = w_i$ for every $i$.
>
> ***Proof:***
>   Let $v_{n+1}, \dotsc, v_m$ be an orthonormal basis of $\langle v_1, \dotsc, v_n \rangle^\perp$ and let $w_{n+1}, \dotsc, w_m \in \langle w_1, \dotsc, w_n \rangle^\perp$ be linearly independent.
>   Then $v_1, \dotsc, v_m$ is a basis of $V$, so there exists a unique linear map $T \colon V \to V$ with $T v_i = w_i$ for every $i$.
>   By assumption and construction we have that
>   $$
>     (T v_i, T v_j)
>   = (w_i, w_j)
>   = (v_i, v_j)
>   \qquad
>   \text{for all $i, j$},
> $$
>   and therefore $(T v, T w) = (v, w)$ for all $v, w \in V$ by bilinearity.

Suppose that $\Psi = \{ \beta_1, \dotsc, \beta_n \}$ and let $\Delta = \{ \alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n \} \subseteq \Phi$ be a simple system such that for all $i, j$ the angle between $\beta_i$ and $\beta_j$ agrees with the angle between $\alpha_i$ and $\alpha_j$.
As $\Phi$ consists of unit vectors it follows that $(\alpha_i, \alpha_j) = (\beta_i, \beta_j)$ for all $i, j$.
By the above lemma there exists an orthogonal transformation $T \colon V \to V$ with $T \alpha_i = \beta_i$ for all $i$.

Since $\Delta$ is a simple system of the root system $\Phi$, it follows that $T \Delta = \Psi$ is a simple system for the root system $T \Phi =: \Phi'$.
We will show that $\Phi' = \Phi$.

Let
$$
  W  := \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Phi \rangle
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  W' := \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Phi' \rangle
$$
be the finite reflection groups associated to the root systems $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$.
By Theorem 1.5 both $W$ and $W'$ are generated by corresponding simple reflections, i.e.
$$
  W  = \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Delta \rangle
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  W' = \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Psi \rangle.
$$
Since $\Psi \subseteq \Phi$ it follows that
$$
            W'
  =         \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Psi \rangle
  \subseteq \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Phi \rangle
  =         W.
$$
On the other hand we have that
\begin{align*}
    W'
  &=  \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Psi \rangle
   =  \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in T \Delta \rangle
   =  \langle s_{T \alpha} \mid \alpha \in \Delta \rangle
\\
  &=  \langle T s_\alpha T^{-1} \mid \alpha \in \Delta \rangle
   =  T \langle s_\alpha \mid \alpha \in \Delta \rangle T^{-1}
   =  T W T^{-1},
\end{align*}
so $W'$ and $W$ have the same cardinality.
Together with $W' \subseteq W$ we find that $W = W'$.

By using Corollary 1.5 it now follows that
$$
            \Phi'
  =         W' \Psi
  =         W \Psi
  \subseteq W \Phi
  =         \Phi.
$$
From $\Phi' = T \Phi$ we also know that $\Phi'$ and $\Phi$ have the same cardinality, so $\Phi' = \Phi$.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I have a more geometric argument that I think can be enlightening to add here. For convenience, I assume the root system spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

First, let us write $\triangle= \{\alpha_1,... \alpha_n\}$ and $\Psi= \{\beta_1,... \beta_n\}$. As was shown on the other answers, the map taking $\alpha_i$ to $\beta_i$ is orthogonal, and in part we see that $\Psi$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, using the lexiographic ordering on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the basis $\Psi$ we see that we may assume $\Psi$ to be positive. Furthermore, because all choices of simple roots are conjugate, we may WLOG assume that $\triangle$ is positive. We are thus reduced to showing $\triangle = \Psi$

By the definition of a choice of simple roots, we see that we may write uniquely: $\beta_i = \Sigma c_{i,j}\alpha_j$ where the $c_{i,j}$ are all non-negative. What does this mean geometerically? Well, consider the rays spanned by the vectors $\alpha_i$, and consider the chamber $C$ closed off by those rays. The points that lie in $C$ are precisely the non-negative linear combinations of the $\alpha_i$. Thus saying that $c_{i,j}>0$ is precisely equivalent to saying that all the $\beta_i$ lie in this chamber. We thus see that our problem will follow from the following problem in geometry:

Claim: If $T$ is an orthogonal transformation such that $T(\alpha_i)\in C$ for all $i$, then necessarily $T$ acts by a permutation of the $\alpha_i$.

Proof: Let $S^{n-1}$ be the sphere of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, and let $\mu$ be the spherical measure on it. Suppose for contradiction that $T$ does not act by permuting the $\alpha_i$, then the chamber $T(C)$ generated by $T(\alpha_i)$ must be strictly contained in $C$, and we thus have $\mu(T(S^{n-1}\cap C))=\mu(S^{n-1}\cap T(C))<\mu(S^{n-1}\cap C)$. But this contradicts the fact that an orthogonal transformation preserves spherical volume.

Comment: "Suppose for contradiction that $T$ does not act by permuting the $\alpha_i$, then the chamber $T(C)$ generated by $T(\alpha_i)$ must be strictly contained in $C$" --- why?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg By assumption each $T(\alpha_i)$ is a positive combination of the $\alpha_i$, and hence by distributivity any positive combination of the $T(\alpha_i)$ is also a positive combination of the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: The strictness follows from the fact there is no way to write $\alpha_i$ as a positive sum of elements in $C - span(\alpha _i)$  (follows easily from linear independence and distribuitivity), hence using that T is orthogonal we see that if $\alpha_i$ is not in the set of  elements $\{ T(\alpha_j) \} \subset C$ it also won't lie in the positive chamber generated by those vectors. Hope this helps!

Comment: OK to that argument, but that leaves open the possibility that the difference between $T(C)$ and $C$ is a set of measure zero ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Remember that we are talking here about sets defined by linear equations, and in the case of taking a sphere section - those are just (curved) convex polyhedra. The difference between the two sets contains a set cut out from $C$ by a finite number of hyperplanes, and is thus of positive measure.

Comment: That said, here's a much more general argument, which fits our intuion about sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ : $C$ is the closure of it's interior, and hence every open subset that intersects $C$ must intersect it's interior. In part, the complement of $T(C)$ intersects the interior of $C$, and thus the difference $C-T(C)$ must contain the non-empty open set $T(C)^c \cap C^{\circ}$, which has positive measure